# avoiding vscodes workspace parent folder showing changed files including files from specific subfolder in repositories tab

Tags: git, github, visual-studio-code

I have 1 parent folder and a subfolder.
Parent folder: "SU (EDIT)"
Subfolder :    "SU SCRIPTS EXTRAS"

Im sending each folder files to a different git repository.

But.. Id like to remove subfolders changed files from parents folder changed files listing inside repositories. This Parent folder is showing a sum of both folders changed files, as expected, but id like to show inside parents folder list (repository changed files) only files outside this subfolder, so it would show each repository changed files indepently.
Theres a way to do that with vscode and/or git (without changing files directories)?

[image]

→ As you can see, 'Su edit' folder sends to a "repository 1" but its not sending anything from 'scripts extras' folder. (removed from exclude folders settings in vscode, only for this screenshot, but its excluded).
→ 'Scripts Extras' subfolder, is added in vs code, so i could send its folders to "repository 2".

[image]

Comment: a git repository inside a git repository is a bad habit, you might try to add the subfolder in the `.gitignore`

Comment: gitignore? its done but folders inside that subfolders folder, get grayed out and tracking files inside subfolders folder stops. 
I must hide in that first folder (that is the parent)
and show in second folder (that is subfolder).

Answer (score 0):

Ive created 2 workspaces:

► One for parent folder only.
► Another for subfolder(s) only.

Thanks.